# Property or method is not defined on the instance but refenced during render

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Error and Background**

I am having some issues getting vue.js to work in my Laravel application. There are no errors whenever I run `gulp`, so I know that my components are compiling. It only happens on runtime, whenever I try to render the components.

Here is the full error that gets logged:

`Property or method "clients" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option. (found in component <clients>)`

The `package.json` file is defined as

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "gulp --production",
    "dev": "gulp watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.1.0",
    "laravel-elixir": "^6.0.0-11",
    "laravel-elixir-vue-2": "^0.2.0",
    "laravel-elixir-webpack-official": "^1.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.16.2",
    "vue": "^2.0.1",
    "vue-loader": "^8.3.0",
    "vue-resource": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-core": "^6.8.0",                                                                                                                 
    "babel-loader":"^6.2.4",                                                                                                              
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime":"^6.8.0",                                                                                           
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",                                                                                                       
    "babel-runtime":"^6.0.0",                                                                                                             
    "vue-hot-reload-api":"^1.2.0",
    "vue-html-loader":"^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried the steps outlined in [this](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/131) GitHub issue, it did not work. I have also, deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm cache clean`. To no avail.

**Application.vue**

```
import Clients from './Clients.vue';

export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('Component ready.')
    },
    components: [
        Clients
    ]
}
```

**Clients.vue**

```
import Client from './Client.vue'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            clients: []
        }
    },
    components: [
        Client
    ],
    mounted() {
        this.$http.get('api/clients').then((response) => {
            this.clients = response.body
        })
    }
}
```

**app.js**

```
require('./bootstrap');

Vue.component('app', require('./components/Application.vue'));
Vue.component('clients', require('./components/Clients.vue'));
Vue.component('client', require('./components/Client.vue'));
```

Comment: What about the rest of the code? HTML template and Client.vue ?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your problem is here:

```
components: [
    Client
],
```

Components should be an object, not an array:

```
components: {
    Client
},
```

Everything else looks OK to me.

Comment: It did not work, I am still getting the same errors.

Comment: I have had issues where the browser caches the `js`, have you checked the `disable cache` checkbox in your developer tools

Comment: I also tried opening the page in Microsoft Edge (I have not used the browser since downloading Chrome). It does not work